# Safely execute tar commands from Java Code for Linux shell

Tags: java, linux

I'm working on a problem where I have to execute a tar command from Java Code

```
tar -xcv output_file_name source_directory
```

This is the code

```
String cmd = "tar -cvzf /tmp/logs.tar.Z /home/test/log/status.*"
try {
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p1.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code is working but it is failing third party security test with possibility of command injection.

I have tried to sanitize my input command by adding regex but the vulnerability is still same.

Can anyone help how to deal with this scenario.
Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using an array for `exec` rather than a string command. It's also better if you ever happen to have spaces in the directory names. And does the `*` really work?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think it is going to work at all.  The `exec(cmd)` call will not deal with the `/home/test/log/status.*` command line argument correctly ... assuming that you want the `status.*` to match all files that start with "status." in that directory.  The `exec` method does not do understand shell syntax such as globbing.

Next, the `-v` option outputs the names of files included in the tar file to standard output.  But you are not consuming standard output.  You should remove the option

My guess is that the security tool is complaining that you are not using the absolute path for `tar`.  There is the possibility that `$PATH` will include (say) "." ... and you will execute a fake `tar` command in the current directory.

So the command probably needs to be this:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "/bin/sh", "-c", 
    "/bin/tar -czf /tmp/logs.tar.Z /home/test/log/status.*");
```

---

If that doesn't solve the problem, please tell us which security tool you are using and show us the complete message, including any error numbers.  If we have more details we may be able to figure out what it is complaining about.

Comment: I am also tried using the absolute path but security vulnerability still exists

Comment: Also, you're asking for verbose output without consuming stdout.

Comment: @g00se - I missed that.  Fixed.